# PHP PDO prevent overlapping data

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating a reservation system for my apartments.
So i want to prevent dates overlapping in reservation (so i do not end up with 2 reservations at same day)

1.Fist i have this "cant post picture" form and calendar page for user to input and submit btn.(where i can prevent days overlapping  before submit button).

2.Second confirmation page "all input info is valid also dates are valid" and final submit button(where also can prevent days overlapping).

My question is: If 2 reservation happens in same time(few second difference eg. both of them on second page,just one click away from reservation) i can't prevent overlapping becaouse neither of reservations is not yet in database and my checking function only compare dates in db.

So i need something to let just one sql insert at time or i do not know would using sql transaction help or is there way to check overlaping in databse but doubt last thing is possible.

```
//MY SQL RESERVATION INSERT METHOD "CALSS METHOD"

  public function insert_korisnik() {

    $conn = new PDO( DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD );
    $sql = "INSERT INTO rezervacije  (dolazak,odlazak,apartman,status) VALUES (:dolazak,:odlazak,:apartman,0)";
    $st = $conn->prepare ( $sql );

    $st->bindValue( ":dolazak", $this->dolazak->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'), PDO::PARAM_STR );
    $st->bindValue( ":odlazak", $this->odlazak->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'), PDO::PARAM_STR );
    $st->bindValue( ":apartman", $this->apartman, PDO::PARAM_STR );

    $st->execute();
    $this->id = $conn->lastInsertId();
    $sql = "";
    $sql = "INSERT INTO gost (id_rezervacije, ime_prezime, adresa, kontakt, datum_rezervacije) VALUES (:id_rezervacije, :ime_prezime, :adresa, :kontakt, :datum_rezervacije)";
    $st = $conn->prepare ( $sql );
    $st->bindValue( ":id_rezervacije", $this->id, PDO::PARAM_INT );
    $st->bindValue( ":ime_prezime", $this->ime_prezime, PDO::PARAM_STR );
    $st->bindValue( ":adresa", $this->adresa, PDO::PARAM_STR );
    $st->bindValue( ":kontakt", $this->kontakt, PDO::PARAM_STR );
    $st->bindValue( ":datum_rezervacije", $this->datum_rezervacije->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'), PDO::PARAM_STR );
    $st->execute();
    $conn = null;


  }








 //PHP INSERTING FUNCTION
    function addReservation() {

      $results=$_POST;
      $results['pageTitle'] = "Nova rezervacija";
      $results['formAction'] = "newReservation";




       if ( isset( $_POST['saveChanges'] ) ) {


        $reservation = new rezervacija_osoba;
        $reservation->storeFormValues_korisnik( $_POST ); 

        if($reservation->last_date_check()){ //CALL TO FUNCTION TO CHECK DATES BEFORE INSERTING "ONLY COMPARES DATES THAT ARE ALREADY IN DB"
            $reservation->insert_korisnik(); // CALL TO SQL INSERT "POSTED CODE UP"

            $email_info=$_POST['email'];
            $comment_info=$_POST['comment'];

            send_email($reservation,$email_info,$comment_info);

            require( TEMPLATE_PATH . "/include/rezervirano.php" );}

        else{
        $error="Looks like another reservation took place during yours that booked same days, to prevent days overllaping please go back and make another reservastin. Thanks";
        display_warning($error);

        }

      } elseif ( isset( $_POST['cancel'] ) ) {

        // CANCEL PRESSD
        header( "Location: index.php" );
      } else {


        require( TEMPLATE_PATH . "/include/potvrda.php" );
      }


      }
```

Comment: JFYI: PDO can't help you to prevent overlapping. It can help you run an SQL query against a database. But SQL is entirely up to you.

Comment: I knew that but i doubt i can prevent this with just sql,i need something lets say that will allow only one sql insert at time and after that one is finished call function to check dates then another sql insert

Comment: Again, PDO has nothing to do with all this stuff.

Comment: Have a look at the sql 'locking' options [/innodb-locks-set](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-locks-set.html). You can use these to serialize sql access to the rows which is exactly what you want. see 'select for update' for example.

Answer (score 0):

You can create  geaman worker (http://gearman.org/)  for this issue and add records successively in 1 thread.